# Apache auto create subdomains

Tags: apache

Hi I need to set my apache to auto create subdomains.
My idea is that at site folder /www/ I will set a script to create folders 
as

> /www/folder1/ ,  /www/folder2/ , /www/folder3/

and I want for each folder to be autocreated subdomain as :

> folder1.mydomain.com , folder2.mydomain.com , folder3.mydomain.com

Perhaps the script must restart the apache at creation.. I don't know.
I hope somebody know how to do that :)

Comment: Do you have a specific question?  Have you tried any of this yourself?

Comment: I don't have any idea how to do that. I think only for php editing of apache file "httpd-vhosts" but I couldn't do it..
And I am not sure will be that security safe.

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, you will likely want to make a template file and then when you run your script, replace some placeholders in it with meaningful values (folder paths/domains) and then save it and restart Apache.

Comment: I think you can achieve this by url rewrite, I'm not proficient with it, but somone wil surely know exactly how to do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [dynamically configured mass virtual hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/vhosts/mass.html) provided by the [mod_vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html) module.

The subdomain themselves are not task for Apache. Just create a wildcard entry in your DNS server.

Comment: Thank you for this, it was usefull :)